# Paired characters in regular expression

Tags: c++, regex, perl

I expect this is very easy, but I can't work out how to match optional character *pairs* in regex. Regular expressions are not something I have ever had to do before.

I want to be able to match "=N","=B","=R" or "=Q" in a character string, optionally -- but if they appear, they must appear paired with the equal sign. So =?[NBRQ]? won't work for me, because someone could type 'N' without the accompanying equal sign. So it must be "=N","=B", "=R" or "=Q" or nothing at all.

Comment: Sample valid examples please. Where should you be able to match this _pair_ ? At beginning, at end or middle of string ?

Comment: @noob: The OP has given the valid character pairs. Where in the string they appear is irrelevant

Comment: @Borodin: From this _I want to be able to match "=N","=B","=R" or "=Q" in a character string_ it seemed like given pattern should appear anywhere in the string. I was going to come up with a solution considering if it appear at start or end.

Answer (score 4):

If you need to make more than one regex production optional, enclose them in parentheses, capturing or non-capturing:

```
(=[NBRQ])?
```

The above would match an optional `=N`, `=B`, `=R`, or `=Q`. Since the question mark appears after parentheses, the entire group is optional, not its individual parts.

Comment: This will capture unnecessarily. `(?:=[NBRQ])?` is better

Comment: @Borodin Sorry, I did mean to say "capturing or non-capturing" instead of "grouping or non-grouping" (I don't even know what's "non-grouping parentheses" would mean). Thanks!